# Alfresco Activiti script task listener current scriptnode?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, activiti

Is there a way to get the ScriptNode that initiated a state in an Activiti workflow in Alfresco? I have a ScriptTask in my workflow, and it has a Alfresco Script Listener set up for the Start event. When the script is called, I'd like the ScriptNode that transitioned into the ScriptTask in the workflow to be passed as a parameter to the function defined as the listener. Is that possible?

Editing for clarity:
Here's a screenshot of Eclispe with the Activiti plugin.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXTbl.jpg

This workflow gets started by another workflow with webscripts.

```
var props = new Object();
var dd = new Date();
props[EL_PROP_WORK_UNIT_NAME] = "testNode" + DateISOString( dd );
props[EL_PROP_WORK_UNIT_SOURCE_CODE] = "ROB";
props[EL_PROP_WORK_UNIT_DELIVERY_DATE] = dd;

node = getHome().createNode(name, EL_TYPE_WORK_UNIT, props);

var EL_WORKFLOW = "activiti$The-workflow";
var activeWfs = node.activeWorkflows;
if( activeWfs === null || activeWfs.length === 0 )
{
    var workflowPackage = workflow.createPackage();
    workflowPackage.addNode( node );
    var workflowDef = workflow.getDefinitionByName(EL_WORKFLOW);
    var workflowPath = workflowDef.startWorkflow( workflowPackage, new Object());
}
```

So the listener calls another javascript method...

```
function artPDFRename()
{
    logger.log("==============================");
    logger.log("<START> artPDFRename");

    var workflowDef = workflow.getDefinitionByName(EL_WORKFLOW);
    var activeInstance = workflowDef.getActiveInstances();
        // ????
}
```

The goal is to have this handling be automatic. We're trying to design this with as little of manual intervention as possible, and are not assigning tasks to users to perform. Yes, there's probably another way to rename a PDF file, but I can't seem to figure out from the documentation listed here how to get a pointer to the node I put in the bpm_package object. That's the question.

Or am I so far off base on how we're developing this that it makes no sense?

Comment: Your last line is very difficult to follow. Please explain what you mean with some code examples so people can follow. I'm not sure, but that could be the case you haven't had a comment/answer for your question.

Comment: I have an Alfresco Script Listener on an Activit task (say a receive task). When a ScriptNode is moving through the workflow and gets to that task, the script is called. I'd like to get a hold of only the ScriptNode that triggered the script to be called.

Comment: ScriptNode is moving through a workflow, you mean the bpm_package right? So when you execute the workflow action you want that node right? Then you need to get the first child from the bpm_package (association). Or isn't this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. The workflow package, which we use as a container for metadata used in the workflow calculations. I can't see how I can get that object from the "workflow" WorkflowManager object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example check the `ScriptTaskListener` class. Here all the workflow variables are put in a map.

The following code is interesting:

> // Add all workflow variables to model
>           Map variables = delegateTask.getExecution().getVariables();
>
> ```
>     for (Entry<String, Object> varEntry : variables.entrySet())
>     {
>         scriptModel.put(varEntry.getKey(), varEntry.getValue());
>     }
> ```

So with this you could use bpm_package as an object within your script within the workflow script task.

So if you need the node were the workflow has run on, the following code should work (where task is your delegateTask from your notify method of the Listener:

> delegateTask.getVariable("bpm_package");
>   // or like the example above
>   delegateTask.getExecution().getVariable("bpm_package");

This will be a list so take the first one and that will be your node.

---------update

If you're using the javascript from alfresco then you can directly use the parent object bpm_package.

So in your case it would be best to do the following:

> var node = bpm_package.children[0]; //or you could check if the
>   package isn't null
>   // Then send the node into your
>   artPDFRename(node); //or you could just add the bpm_package code in
>   your js file

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that I'm attempting to do this via web scripts. I'll see if that translates to available methods in the workflow objects.

Comment: ? I'm totally confused right now. How does the task gets to a webscript. I haven't seen a tag/listener/method for that. I think you need to fully expose your code/steps here otherwise your won't really get help.

Comment: Updated with more info. Thanks.

Comment: The bpm_package object, that's what I needed. Didn't see that in the documentation anywhere, didn't know it existed. Thanks.

Comment: It is ;) here at the Wiki of Alfresco: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Process_Data